# Taxonomy Term Reference Fields Don't Get Created on Nodes During Migration

Tags: 8, migrations

I have followed the steps shown [here](https://drupalize.me/blog/201604/custom-drupal-drupal-migrations-migrate-tools) to create/run the migration.  Everything seems to migrate correctly except the Taxonomy Term Reference fields never get added to the nodes.  The taxonomies and vocabularies do get created.

I'm thinking that those fields should have been created in d6_field_instance so here is my migrate_plus.migration.upgrade_d6_field_instance.yml.

```
uuid: 6e1fd6ac-1ec4-4631-93d1-753068fdc667
langcode: en
status: true
dependencies: {  }
id: upgrade_d6_field_instance
migration_tags:
  - 'Drupal 6'
migration_group: migrate_drupal_6
label: 'Field instance configuration'
source:
  plugin: d6_field_instance
  constants:
    entity_type: node
process:
  field_type_exists:
    -
      plugin: migration
      migration: upgrade_d6_field
      source:
        - field_name
    -
      plugin: extract
      index:
        - 1
    -
      plugin: skip_on_empty
      method: row
  entity_type: constants/entity_type
  field_name: field_name
  bundle:
    -
      plugin: migration
      migration: upgrade_d6_node_type
      source: type_name
    -
      plugin: skip_on_empty
      method: row
  label: label
  description: description
  required: required
  status: active
  settings:
    plugin: d6_field_field_settings
    source:
      - widget_type
      - widget_settings
      - global_settings
  default_value_callback: ''
  default_value:
    plugin: d6_field_instance_defaults
    source:
      - widget_type
      - widget_settings
destination:
  plugin: 'entity:field_config'
migration_dependencies:
  required:
    - upgrade_d6_node_type
    - upgrade_d6_field
  optional:
    - upgrade_d6_field
    - upgrade_d6_node_type
```

Any idea what it can point me where in code to look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem wasn't in migrate_plus.migration.upgrade_d6_field_instance.yml but instead the problems were in  migrate_plus.migration.upgrade_d6_field.ym and migrate_plus.migration.upgrade_d6_field_instance_widget_settings.yml.  Also in the term yml files I had to update the field name to include `field_` in the file name.

I documented how I was debugging and what I was changing [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2863473).